# How to make template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, function-pointers

How do I create a metafunction that takes any kind of function pointer? In the code below, how do I get rid of "decltype(&f)" ?

```
template <class FuncType, FuncType functionPointer>
void runFunc()
{
    functionPointer();
}

runFunc<decltype(&f),f>();
```

I don't want to have to specify the type of f seperately; the information is already there in f. I'd prefer not to resort to defines to solve this.
This is basically the templated function type idiom applied to meta-programming; I don't want to know the type of f, but whatever I get in apparently allows me to call operator() on it.

Stuff I've tried:

Different order for the template parameters; since later parameters seem to be guessable when you have a function; not possible because then you would need to forward declare FuncType, in order to have it as the type for functionPointer

Switching it around so that you specify returntype and parameters and give a function pointer of that type; cannot instantiate a template with variable template arguments in the middle; that looks like below:

```
template <class ReturnType, class ... ArgTypes, ReturnType (*functionPointer)(ArgTypes...)>
void runFunc()
{
    functionPointer();
}

runFunc<void, int, f>(); // error; invalid template argument for 'ArgTypes', type expected
```

There's a bit more context here on github: https://github.com/TamaHobbit/FuncTest/blob/master/FuncTest/FuncTest.cpp

Comment: Any reason you can't remove `FuncPointer functionPointer` and take it as a parameter instead?

Comment: runFunc will be made to match the functionPointer's signature; this is not possible if the function pointer is passed as a runtime parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is unfortunately no good way of doing this.

The standard committee has, however, accepted a proposal that makes this valid code:

```
template <auto functionPointer>
void runFunc() {
  functionPointer();
}
```

Compiler support should be coming soon.

Comment: Could you edit your answer now that C++17 supports the code you posted? Note though that Visual Studio alone has not implemented auto template types.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
template <typename FuncType>
void runFunc(FuncType functionPointer )
{
    functionPointer();
}

runFunc(f);
```

Comment: That misses the point entirely; that's just the templated function type idiom, I want runFunc to take a function pointer as a template parameter, so that the signature of runFunc can be made to match the function pointer's signature.

Comment: Thats a shame! Unfortunately, I still don't get the point so can't offer a better answer than what I have given you. Best of luck!

Comment: There are two major differences between passing the function's type as the template parameter, and passing the function itself as the template parameter. First, two functions with the same signature should yield different templated function instances for my purposes, so that I can cache the results with a function-local static map of parameters to return type (see the link I gave for context). Second, passing the function at runtime means one more thing on the stack and another pointer to traverse at runtime. My goal is to cache functions generically, but just as efficiently as custom code.