# Simplifying template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Take the following struct:

```
template<typename T,T value>
struct A{
};
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
A<12> a;  //A<12> should become A<int,12>
```

But this is not allowed.  Why is it not allowed? (and is there a workaround?)

Comment: Someone asked the same question about function templates here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232082/how-to-make-template-parameter I can't mark this a duplicate until my answer is upvoted or accepted though.

Comment: Can't think of a way, except for a type alias. Something like `template<int N> using A_t = A<int, N>;`. Note that this will introduce another type. If it isn't what you want, then the initial class is probably badly designed.

Comment: If memory serves, one of the things voted into C++17 was `template<auto value>` Never mind, it's up for vote in Oulu (end of June).

Comment: Think for a moment about what you're trying to achieve here.  I assume it's ease of use, and that A is usually a container of ints, but not always.  I'd leave it the standard way, `template <typename T, T value>...`, but if it's important to not have to type `int`, you can do this:      `template<typename T, T value> struct A{}; ` and `template<T value> struct AWithInts: A<int, value> {};`

Comment: What is 12? A char, short, int, long, size_t, double?

Comment: I think he wants 12 to be int by default.  If it is to be any other type, then it the type must be explicitly stated after the 12, like the class `C<int, typename = int>` in my solution.

Comment: @RichardHodges By default any unspecified number is an `int` in c++.  But theoretically I would want this to work for `A<(char)12>` also...but that doesn't seem likely

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but perhaps this?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T value>
struct A {
    void foo() const { std::cout << "A<int, " << value << ">::foo called\n"; }
};

// Sample partial specialization that you might want.
template <std::size_t value>
struct A<std::size_t, value> {
    void foo() const { std::cout << "A<std::size_t, " << value << ">::foo called\n"; }
};

template <int N>
using B = A<int, N>;

template <int N, typename T = int>
using C = A<T, static_cast<T>(N)>;

int main() {
    B<12> a;
    a.foo();  // A<int, 12>::foo called
    C<12> c;
    c.foo();  // A<int, 12>::foo called
    C<12, std::size_t> d;
    d.foo();  // A<std::size_t, 12>::foo called
}
```

Comment: @DarthRubik    I expanded my answer a bit.  Perhaps `C` is closer to what you want than `B`?  But `A<12>` is illegal syntax because its declaration forces a type to be listed first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the closest you're going to get is to use a meta-factory:

```
template<class T, T value>
struct A
{};


template<class T = int>
struct factory
{
  template<T V> using A = ::A<T, V>;
};

int main()
{
  auto x = factory<>::A<12> {};
  auto y = factory<short>::A<45> {};
}
```